# Core dump when trying to access a pointer to a structure passed to a function in solaris

Tags: c, structure, solaris, coredump

I have a quite complicated code in that is working fine on AIX but core dumping in Solaris. I tried to make it as simplified as possible.

Below is a global structrue having a pointer to a function

```
 custom_struct_1 my_struct1 = {
      intValue1, intValue2, intValue3, func3
   };
```

This is a second structure having a pointer to the first one as a field

```
  custom_struct_2 my_struct2 = {
      intValue1, intValue2, &my_struct1
  };
```

below is the flow

```
func1(){

   custom_struct *my_dumping_struct;
   memset(my_struct, 0, sizeof(my_struct);

   func2(my_dumping_struct, &my_struct2);


 }

func2(custom_struct *my_dumping_struct, custom_struct_2 *my_struct2 ){

   custom_struct1 *my_cust1;
   // Some conditions go here 

   my_cust1 = &my_struct2->custom_struct_1;

   my_cust1->struct_func(my_dumping_struct);

}


func3(custom_struct *my_dumping_struct)
{
    // Here when trying to access any field of the passed structure
    // a core dump is occuring
    if(my_dumping_struct->intValue1 == 0)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help. It is driving me crazy. I tried multipile things like defining the dumping structure without a pointer at first, using

```
  memset(&my_dumping_structre, 0, sizeof(my_dumping_struct))
```

and passing it with a reference to the other functions it still core dumps.

*EDIT*

Definition of the structures are as below:

```
 struct custom_struct {
            int intValue1;
            int intValue2;
         };

         struct custom_struct_1 {

            int intValue1;
            int intValue2;
            int intValue3;
            int (*struct_func)(custom_struct *my_struct);
         };

         struct custom_struct_2 {
            int intValue1;
            int intValue2;
            struct custom_struct_1 *my_struct;
         };
```

Thanks

Comment: Since you posted almost everything else, I don't suppose you could post the definitions of `custom_struct_1`, `custom_struct_2`, and `custom_struct` ?? *In the question please; **not** as a comment*. While you're at it, code that *compiles* would be a nice touch. As-written `func1()` has two undefined variables and uses undeclared types. `func2()` and `func3()` are no better off. An [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) would be highly desirable. Don't "tell" us about your code; just *post it*, along with what you're expecting, what your getting, and what you speculate is wrong.

Comment: I guess you're right, was going to do it :)

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry can't share whole code, even if I could it might take ages to pick it up, each structure is defined in a different header file and has a lot more elements than those described.

Comment: Out of the frying pan an into the fire. Now we have things like `p_flddata`, `p_fmt`, and `p_sub`, and absolutely no idea what *any* of them are. Throw this all aside and put together a **small**, self-contained, **compilable** example (an [(SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/)) of the fundamental problem you're having. Throwing up a bunch of undefined data types and variables is ultimately a long road to nowhere. While putting together your sample, don't be surprised if you actually *find your problem yourself* and solve it outright. It happens more than you think.

Comment: sorry, part of the initial code forgotten, will try and do a compiling sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

malloc seemed to solve the problem

```
custom_struct *my_dumping_struct  = malloc(sizeof *my_dumping_struct);
```

Sorry if wasn't very clear and thanks all for your suggestions and help

Answer (score 0):

The expression `&my_struct2->custom_struct_1` doesn't do what you expect it to do. It returns the address of the *pointer*, in other words a pointer to a pointer to the `custom_struct_1` structure.

Don't use the address-of operator `&` and it should work *much* better.

You have this problem in more places, actually almost everywhere you use a pointer you take the address of the pointer instead.

You might also have another problem, unless you don't show us the complete code of `func1`, and that is that you don't initialize the `my_dumping_struct` pointer before using it. That means it will point to a seemingly random address, and all dereferencing of that pointer will be *undefined behavior* and most likely a crash.

Actually, you should have **lots** of compiler warnings screaming at you about all of this.

Comment: Surprisingly no, I'm not getting any compilation warnings. The dumping struct is not initialized. My understanding is memset will fill it all zeros, when passed to other functions, it might be filled with other values depending on the logic of course

Comment: @wassim When you declare a local variable, it doesn't matter if it's a pointer or not, it's not initialize, That means that the contents of that variable will be whatever is on the stack on that variables position when the function is called. This means that pointers will point to somewhere unknown in memory, maybe even to somewhere that contains some data for another structure. Dereferencing this uninitialized pointer will then access this random memory. You must **always** initialize pointers, either assigning it to another pointer or by allocating memory for what it should point to.

Comment: @wassim If you don't get warnings, you should turn on more warnings (I recommend `-Wall -Wextra` on GCC (at the least)). These issues are serious and will cause (maybe severe and hard to trace) crashes if you don't understand them.

Comment: @wassim You should also learn the difference between the address-of operator `&`, and the dereference operators `*`, `->` and `.`.